# How to add to a DVC stage outputs already tracked by DVC?

Tags: dvc

In my project, I already have some files tracked by DVC that I added with `dvc add`. And now I want to create stages using thses files as outputs and dependencies, but when I try to create a stage I get an error that says `ERROR: output '[FILE NAME]' is already specified in stages`.

I assume that `dvc add` add the files to the dependency graph as outputs, thus when I try to include them in a stage it creates a conflict, but I couldn't find anything on the official docuemntation confirming it. So now am confused on how to add outputs to a stage is theses outputs are already tracked by DVC.

Here is an example of what the error I get when creating a stage

```
>>> dvc stage add -n train -d data/data.csv -o models/model python train.py

ERROR: output 'models/model' is already specified in stages:
        - models/model.dvc
        - train
```

In this example the file `data/data.csv` and directory `models/model` are already added to dvc but are not added to any stage, however they are present in the dependency graph.

So how do I include theses files into a DVC Stage ? Is there a way to do it without having to remove the files from DVC then add them directly through a Stage?

Comment: I don't understand why you thought you had to add *DVC |* to your post title when you used it twice more in the title itself, you tagged it DVC, and you use DVC seven more times in the post body, so I removed it. It's pretty clear that your question is about DVC without the added noise.

Comment: @kenWhite My bad I just saw a previous question with the same format I went with it

Comment: As a general rule, it's not necessary to use the tag info in the title at all, as the tag system works extremely well. The exceptions are for rare cases where the use in the title clarifies something specific (you''re using a new version of something that does not yet have a tag available, so you tag with the current version and mention the new one in the title, for example). SO goes so far as to incorporate the tags in the SEO information, so search engines can use them to help find questions that use them along with the title and content.

Comment: @kenWhite Okay, that's noted for future questions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DVC stage outputs are automatically tracked by DVC, you don't need to do `dvc add` on them. If you already have done it before, you can safely un-track it with  [`dvc remove`](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/remove#example-remove-a-dvc-file) first:

> Note that the actual output files or directories of the stage (`outs` field) are not removed by this command, unless the `--outs` option is used.

One thing to mention / note. When you create a stage and run it, it removes outputs (unless a persistence flag is specified). This done for reproducibility, it's expected that your stage produces its outputs every time it runs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I guess I'll just remove them first then. But what do you mean by `When you create a stage and run it, it removes outputs` ? Do you mean that they get deleted when I run the stage, or after I have run the stage ? If I run the stages with `dvc repro` for example and then do a `dvc push` the outputs should be tracked in my remote right?

Comment: Yes, if you run `dvc repro` + `dvc push` they will produced and DVC-tracked and saved. What I was trying to say (may be it's obvious, but worth making a note I think) - is that when you do `dvc repro` (or `dvc exp run`) existing stage outputs are deleted.